# ¿Cómo dividir las columnas de un xts entre las columnas de otro por nombre?

Tags: r, data, timeseries

Tengo dos objetos de clase `xts`, `df1` y `df2` que lucen de la siguiente forma respectivam:

```
           |Argentina   |Peru  |Chile  |Colombia    |Brasil   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-01 |4           |12    |16     |8           |32       |
2018-01-01 |14          |18    |6      |4           |82       |
2019-01-01 |64          |22    |14     |18          |52       |
2020-01-01 |24          |80    |36     |6           |14       |
2021-01-01 |34          |70    |36     |60          |74       |


           |Argentina   |Colombia  |Chile  |Peru  |Brasil    |
----------------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-01 |1           |1         |16     |12     |2        |
2018-01-01 |7           |2         |3      |2      |41       |
2019-01-01 |16          |18        |1      |11     |13       |
2020-01-01 |8           |2         |3      |40     |7       |
2021-01-01 |17          |30        |6      |35     |74       |
```

Y quiero dividir cada elemento de cada columna en `df1` entre el elemento en la misma fecha en la columna correspondiente (por país, es decir por el nombre de la columna) en `df2`. Por ejemplo dividir cada elemento de la columna `"Chile"` en `df1` por el elemento que le corresponda por fecha de la columna `"Chile"` en `df2` para obtener el dataframe `df3`:

```
           |Argentina   |Peru  |Chile  |Colombia    |Brasil   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-01 |4           |1     |1      |8           |16       |
2018-01-01 |2           |9     |2      |2           |2        |
2019-01-01 |4           |2     |14     |1           |4        |
2020-01-01 |3           |2     |12     |3           |2        |
2021-01-01 |2           |2     |6      |2           |1        |
```

Se me ocurre hacer `df1/df2` pero como las columnas en los xts no tienen el mismo orden, el resultado que obtengo no tiene sentido... Podrían ayudarme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero debes reordenar el `df2` para que coincidan con las columnas de `df1`. Si estas seguras que los nombres de las columnas son las mismas puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
df2_reordenado <- df2[, names(df1)]
```

y luego dividir

```
df3 <- df1 / df2_reordenado
```

o sin usar un objeto intermedio

```
df3 <- df1 / df2[, names(df1)]
```

Comment: Gracias! Esto resuelve el problema!